# How to color column if certain conditions match

Tags: excel, vba

I want to implement some logic into my scheduler but I don't really have the know how on how to check for values in a column.
What I would like to implement, is to check if the values `"F"` and `"S"` exists at least once in a day, otherwise the column should be colored.
Furthermore I would like to check if the values `"U"`, `"SCH"` and `"ZA"` do not occur more than 3 times in a given day, otherewise the column should again be colored.

Here is an example if the discription given isn't enough:

[image]

Legend:

```
F = early Shift,
S = late Shift,
U = Vacation,
ZA = compensatory time,
SCH = training
```

Comment: use [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Comment: I have tried to use conditional formatting, but I haven't been successfull in doing so by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luuk sugested try this formula in conditional formating (adjust it by yourself):

```
=OR(OR(COUNTIF(B:B,"F")<1,COUNTIF(B:B,"S")<1),(COUNTIF(B:B,"U")+COUNTIF(B:B,"SCH")+COUNTIF(B:B,"ZA"))>2)
```

Result should look like this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

- The idea of the code is to set the range manually - `Range("A1:P20")`.
- Then with a nested loop, it checks the values of each cell in the range, if it is part of the `Array("U", "SCH", "ZA, "F", "S")`.
- If it is, the column of the cell is highlighted in yellow with this part of the code - `myRange.Columns(myCell.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow`

---

```
Sub ColorMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P20")
    Dim myCell As Range
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Array("U", "SCH", "ZA", "F", "S")
    Dim myItem As Variant
    
    For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
        For Each myItem In myArray
            If myItem = UCase(Trim(myCell)) Then
                myRange.Columns(myCell.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Using the points above and your business logic, you may introduce a variable, deciding whether the column of the range should be colored or not.